# Geth node taking way too long to sync

Tags: go-ethereum, raspberry-pi

I have synchronizing geth node running on a Raspberry Pi Model B (8 GB RAM) with an external 1TB SSD attached via USB-3 running Arch Linux.

I've been "synchronizing" for about 5 days or so now. My "currentBlock" is always fluctuating between 50-100 blocks away from "highestBlock" count. I'm using snap sync and, looking at the docs, it seems to be normal for there to be a period of time where the node doesn't *quite* reach the highestBlock count but eventually does.

Why is it taking *this* long? Here's the command I've used to start geth:

`geth --datadir geth --signer=geth/clef/clef.ipc --mainnet --syncmode snap --cache 4096 --mine`

As you'll likely see, I'm running clef as the address signer and have had no issues with that thus far.

Is it possible that the Rpi 4 doesn't have the necessary hardware power to sync a node? Have I screwed something up?

EDIT: My geth datadir is approximately 566GB and the download seems to have slowed down considerably at this point as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The solution was simply more time. The resources at my disposal claimed that an RPi would be able to sync in a matter of 2-3 days with a speedy internet connection. For me, it took about a week.

I am fully synced up now!

Comment: If you are in a hurry, you can use the `--syncmode "light"` option.